# express download csv attachment on response not working

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, download, stream

Hello im trying to send a response from a post req that includes download attachment. I get the correct response, but no download or save-as pop up. I checked and headers are correctly set. Im using express, mongodb, mongoose, and nextjs. This controller function takes a start and end date from the request and queries collection. cvsReadStream streams to csv table format and then pipes to response.

controller:

```
exports.postExportApplications = (req, res, next) => {
  const startDate = new Date(req.body.startDate)
  const endDate = new Date(req.body.endDate)
  const fileName = `${moment(startDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY')}-${moment(endDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY')}-Applications.csv`
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.attachment(fileName)
    return Application.find({ dateTime: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } } )
      .sort({ dateTime: 1 })
      .then(applications => {
        Application.csvReadStream(applications)
          .pipe(res)
      })
  } else {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
}
```

response headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="12-13-1994-12-20-2020-Applications.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 14 Dec 2019 22:42:10 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

form component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import InputMask from 'react-input-mask'

const ExportAppsForm = (props) => {

  const defaultData = {
    startDate: { value: '', error: false },
    endDate: { value: '', error: false },
  }

  const [form, setform] = useState(defaultData)

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target
    const name = target.name
    setform({
        ...form,
        [name]: target.value
    })
  }

  const submitform = () => {
    props.handleFormSubmit({...form})
  }

  return (
    <form encType="multipart/form-data">
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor="year">Start Date:</label>
          <InputMask 
            mask="99/99/9999"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={form.startDate}
            name="startDate"
            className="form-control"
            id="startDate"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor="make">End Date:</label>
          <InputMask 
            mask="99/99/9999"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={form.endDate}
            name="endDate"
            className="form-control"
            id="endDate"
            />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={submitform} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Export Now!</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default ExportAppsForm;
```

axios post request:

```
export const postExportApplications = (query) => {
  return axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/export`, query).then(res => res.data)
}
```

Comment: What's the issue here? no file being sent?

Comment: @Unknown correct. nothing pops up.

Comment: Could you post the client side and also see what the console.log of response there says?

Comment: what happens when you request your file from your browser

Comment: By the way, there is no explicit question there, please edit your post

Comment: @Unknown i edited the post to include client side, but i was getting my response correctly. It's just no save-as popup for download.

Comment: @Léo Martin i fixed my question. No download for attachment popup with correct headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just making a query to get your data in csv format so an HTTP GET method is the most appropriate for this case since you are not modifying any resources 
see: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/.

So first of all you have to alter your controller to accept the query as query parameters and make a GET request using axios as shown below

```
export const getCsv = (params) => {
  axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '[YOUR_URL_HERE]'
      params,            
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      headers: {
         'Accept': 'text/csv'
      }
  }).then(response => {
     if(response.status === 200 && response){
        return response.data;
     }
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));         
}
```

**To download the csv file in your class component**
Using a package called file-saver

```
npm i file-saver
```

and import the package as follows

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
```

In your component you can then use the getCSv function for your onClick handler

```
funcion onHandleDownload(query) => {
   getCsv(query).then(data => {
      const blob = new Blob([data], {
           type: 'text.csv',
       });
       saveAs(blob, 'csv_name.csv')
   })
}
```